# Sort bibliography in order of appearance

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies, sorting

I'm trying to use `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` to sort my bibliography in order of appearance. From [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226137/bibliographystyle-invalid-what-am-i-doing-wrong-in-my-latex-file-or-bibtex-file) I know that I can't mix the `biblatex` package with `\bibliographystyle`. However, when I remove `biblatex` another compile error arises on a different line.

Here's what I have tried...

```
% BEGIN -- SETUP DOCUMENT (OVERLEAF) --
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\let\cite\parencite
\begin{document}
% END -- SETUP DOCUMENT (OVERLEAF) --


\title{ Machine Learning for 3D Segmentation }
\author{Kendall Weihe}
\date{October 27, 2016}
\maketitle

\printbibliography[title=References]
\nocite{*}

\end{document}
```

It throws an error at the line `\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}`

Comment: Of course, if you remove `biblatex`, `\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}`  is not defined, nor `\addbibresource nor `\printbibliography`If you want the equivalent of the `unsrt` bib style, load biblatex with the `[sorting=none]`  option. `

Comment: If you want to use `biblatex`, remove `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` and load `biblatex` with the `sorting=none` option: `\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}`. Note that `\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}` is only necessary (and should probably only be used) with `style=apa`.

Comment: Any news here? Did you try the suggestions?

Comment: yes, sorry forgot about this. @moewe suggestion worked, thanks! feel free to write an answer

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You cannot mix BibTeX and `biblatex`.

In your code remove `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` (which is BibTeX language) and load `biblatex` with `sorting=none`

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblat‌​ex}
```

You will probably not need `\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}`, which is only necessary if you use the `biblatex-apa` style.

Comment: I did it but just label names are showed now. I compile bunch of times but still like that.

Comment: @ömerkoçhan Please consider asking a new question with an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864), a description of what you are doing, what errors or warnings you get and what the output looks like.