# Bibliography style unsrt not getting it right

Tags: bibtex, bibliographystyle

I’m getting really confused about what is doing what. I used to work with `biblatex-chicago`, but now I need to change, and I would like to use the bibliography style `unsrt`; I want to have my references numbered in the order they appear in the main text.

After attempts trying to implement `unsrt` bibliography style in my .tex document, I gave up and thought I found another way by simply using `biblatex` as is, adding the bib resource, and everything seemed to work. That didn’t unfortunately as I was just lucky to have alphabetical ordered references, so it simply *seemed* to work.

Here is what I did firt:

#### Input #1

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}   
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[colorlinks,hidelinks,urlcolor=blue,bookmarks=false,hypertexnames=true]{hyperref}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{202F}{\,}

\usepackage{biblatex} 


\addbibresource{5G.bib}
\author{}
\title{}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    
     text\cite{5G2022} text \cite{adrianjpullinDesignConsiderations5G2013} text \cite{hargittaiDigitalReproductionInequality2018}, text \cite{ReportSpecialRapporteur2011}, text \cite{DeclaresInternetAccess2011}. text \cite{nyamapfeneImpending5GEra2016}
    
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Then I tried with using `bibliographystyle{unsrt}` and it kind of work, it simply that my references do not display correctly.

#### Input #2:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}   
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{202F}{\,}
\usepackage[colorlinks,hidelinks,urlcolor=blue,bookmarks=false,hypertexnames=true]{hyperref} 

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}


\author{}
\title{Title}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    
     text\cite{5G2022} text \cite{adrianjpullinDesignConsiderations5G2013} text \cite{hargittaiDigitalReproductionInequality2018}, text \cite{ReportSpecialRapporteur2011}, text \cite{DeclaresInternetAccess2011}. text \cite{nyamapfeneImpending5GEra2016}
    
    \bibliography{5G.bib}
\end{document}
```

So basically, what I need is: for the list of references at the end of document the output should look like #1, but for the number referencing to the list the output should be #2.

#### output #1:

[image]

#### output #2:

[image]

This is the bib file:

```
@inreference{5G2022,
  title = {{{5G}}},
  booktitle = {Wikipedia},
  date = {2022-03-13T21:40:58Z},
  url = {https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=5G&oldid=1076960026},
  urldate = {2022-03-14},
  abstract = {},
  langid = {english},
  annotation = {Page Version ID: 1076960026},
  file = {/home/louisvgn/Zotero/storage/DUSRMKCJ/5G.html}
}

@article{adrianjpullinDesignConsiderations5G2013,
  title = {Design {{Considerations}} for {{5G Mobile Network}}},
  author = {{Adrian J Pullin} and Mehedi Shams Rony},
  date = {2013-01},
  journaltitle = {International Journal of Computer Applications},
  volume = {62},
  number = {10},
  pages = {14--21},
  url = {https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.303.3268&rep=rep1&type=pdf},
  langid = {english}
}

@online{DeclaresInternetAccess2011,
  title = {‘{{UN}} Declares {{Internet}} Access a Human Right’ – Did It Really? - {{Diplo}}},
  shorttitle = {‘{{UN}} Declares {{Internet}} Access a Human Right’ – Did It Really?},
  date = {2011-06-10T11:28:53+02:00},
  url = {https://www.diplomacy.edu/blog/un-declares-internet-access-human-right-did-it-really/},
  urldate = {2022-03-14},
  abstract = {‘UN declares Internet access a human right’ – did it really? The ‘scoop’ headlines read ‘UN declares Internet access a human right’, ‘Internet access is a},
  langid = {british},
  file = {/home/louisvgn/Zotero/storage/5WLLISCQ/un-declares-internet-access-human-right-did-it-really.html}
}

@book{hargittaiDigitalReproductionInequality2018,
  title = {The Digital Reproduction of Inequality},
  author = {Hargittai, Eszter},
  date = {2018},
  publisher = {{Routledge}},
  isbn = {0-429-49446-7},
  pagetotal = {11}
}

@article{nyamapfeneImpending5GEra2016,
  title = {The {{Impending 5G Era}} and {{Its Likely Impact}} on {{Society}}},
  author = {Nyamapfene, A.},
  date = {2016-01},
  journaltitle = {Journal of Independent Studies and Research - Computing},
  volume = {14},
  number = {1},
  pages = {43--47},
  publisher = {{Shaheed Zulfiqar Ali Bhutto Institute of Science and Technology}},
  issn = {2412-0448},
  url = {https://doi.org/10.31645/jisrc/(2016).14.1.0007},
  urldate = {2022-03-14},
  abstract = {},
  issue = {1},
  langid = {english},
  file = {/home/louisvgn/Zotero/storage/VPTCPLI5/Nyamapfene - 2016 - The Impending 5G Era and Its Likely Impact on Soci.pdf;/home/louisvgn/Zotero/storage/TKNB82FV/10096520.html}
}

@report{ReportSpecialRapporteur2011,
  title = {Report of the {{Special Rapporteur}} on the Promotion and Protection of the Right to Freedom of Opinion and Expression, {{Frank La Rue}}},
  year = {16\,May 2011},
  number = {A/HRC/12/27},
  pages = {22},
  institution = {{United Nations}},
  location = {{General Assembly}},
  url = {https://www2.ohchr.org/english/bodies/hrcouncil/docs/17session/A.HRC.17.27_en.pdf},
  langid = {english}
}
```

Thank you very much for your help in advance. It would save my life!

Comment: The way to get the `unsrt` sorting by appearance in `biblatex` is with `sorting=none,`. So `\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, sorting=none,]{biblatex}` (if we want to be a bit more explicit than necessary). See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51434/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/336237/35864.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Answer based on moewe’s comment:

The way to get the `unsrt` sorting by appearance in biblatex is with `sorting=none,`. So `\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, sorting=none,]{biblatex}` (if we want to be a bit more explicit than necessary). See also [tex.stackexchange.com/q/51434/35864](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51434/35864) and [tex.stackexchange.com/a/337117/252672](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/337117/252672)

Answer (score 1):

My first piece of advice would be to keep trying to make `biblatex` (and `biber`) work for you.

However, if you cannot get it work and you decide to wish to swich to a BibTeX-based work flow, here are some suggestions:

- Use `unsrtnat`, not the ancient `unsrt` bib style. And, load the `natbib` citation management package as well as the `xurl` package. That way, `url` fields will get processed properly.
- Replace all instances of `journaltitle` with `journal`.
- BibTeX styles don't recognize the `date` field. I suggest you add `year` fields that contain -- you guessed it -- the year of publication, for each bibliographic entry that's missing a `year` field.
- Where possible, backfill missing `author` fields with suitably chosen authors.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}   
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{5G.bib}
@misc{5G2022,
  title = {{5G}},
  author = {Wikipedia},
  year = 2022,
  date = {2022-03-13T21:40:58Z},
  url = {https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=5G&oldid=1076960026},
  urldate = {2022-03-14},
  abstract = {},
  langid = {english},
  annotation = {Page Version ID: 1076960026},
  file = {/home/louisvgn/Zotero/storage/DUSRMKCJ/5G.html}
}

@article{adrianjpullinDesignConsiderations5G2013,
  title = {Design {Considerations} for {5G Mobile Network}},
  author = {Adrian J. Pullin and Mehedi Shams Rony},
  year = 2013,
  date = {2013-01},
  journal = {International Journal of Computer Applications},
  volume = {62},
  number = {10},
  pages = {14--21},
  url = {https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.303.3268&rep=rep1&type=pdf},
  langid = {english}
}

@online{DeclaresInternetAccess2011,
  title = {{UN} Declares {Internet} Access a Human Right --- Did It Really? --- {Diplo}},
  shorttitle = {‘{UN} Declares {Internet} Access a Human Right’ – Did It Really?},
  year = 2011,
  date = {2011-06-10T11:28:53+02:00},
  url = {https://www.diplomacy.edu/blog/un-declares-internet-access-human-right-did-it-really/},
  urldate = {2022-03-14},
  abstract = {‘UN declares Internet access a human right’ – did it really? The ‘scoop’ headlines read ‘UN declares Internet access a human right’, ‘Internet access is a},
  langid = {british},
  file = {/home/louisvgn/Zotero/storage/5WLLISCQ/un-declares-internet-access-human-right-did-it-really.html}
}

@book{hargittaiDigitalReproductionInequality2018,
  title = {The Digital Reproduction of Inequality},
  author = {Hargittai, Eszter},
  year = 2018,
  date = {2018},
  publisher = {Routledge},
  isbn = {0-429-49446-7},
  pagetotal = {11}
}

@article{nyamapfeneImpending5GEra2016,
  title = {The {Impending 5G Era} and Its Likely Impact on Society},
  author = {Nyamapfene, A.},
  year = 2016,
  date = {2016-01},
  journal = {Journal of Independent Studies and Research -- Computing},
  volume = {14},
  number = {1},
  pages = {43--47},
  publisher = {Shaheed Zulfiqar Ali Bhutto Institute of Science and Technology},
  issn = {2412-0448},
  url = {https://doi.org/10.31645/jisrc/(2016).14.1.0007},
  urldate = {2022-03-14},
  abstract = {},
  issue = {1},
  langid = {english},
  file = {/home/louisvgn/Zotero/storage/VPTCPLI5/Nyamapfene - 2016 - The Impending 5G Era and Its Likely Impact on Soci.pdf;/home/louisvgn/Zotero/storage/TKNB82FV/10096520.html}
}

@techreport{ReportSpecialRapporteur2011,
  author={{United Nations}},
  title = {Report of the {Special Rapporteur} on the Promotion and Protection of the Right to Freedom of Opinion and Expression, {Frank La Rue}},
  year = 2011,
  date = {16\,May 2011},
  number = {A/HRC/12/27},
  pages = {22},
  institution = {United Nations},
  location = {General Assembly},
  url = {https://www2.ohchr.org/english/bodies/hrcouncil/docs/17session/A.HRC.17.27_en.pdf},
  langid = {english}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}

\begin{document}
    
\cite{5G2022} 
\cite{adrianjpullinDesignConsiderations5G2013} 
\cite{hargittaiDigitalReproductionInequality2018}
\cite{ReportSpecialRapporteur2011}
\cite{DeclaresInternetAccess2011}
\cite{nyamapfeneImpending5GEra2016}
    
\bibliography{5G}
\end{document}
```

Comment: First of, thank you very much for this answer. I’d like to stick to `biblatex` and `biber` actually, but I don’t know how to make it work the right way.